# Why can't static classes have non-static methods and variables?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, class, static

Why can't static classes have non-static methods and variables when non-static classes can have static methods and variables?

What is the advantage of having static methods and variables in a non static class? Though having a static constructor in a non-static class is understandable.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Static classes can't be instantiated in the first place, so even if you could declare non-static (instance) members, they can never be accessed. Since there really isn't a point allowing it for that reason, the language simply prohibits it.

Bear in mind that static classes are *just the classes*, while there are two things that are directly related to non-static classes: *the classes* themselves, and *the instances/objects* of the classes.

A non-static class can have both static and non-static members so that the static members apply to the class, whereas the non-static members apply to the instances of that class.

Answer (score 3):

Static class can't contain non-static members because by definition it can't be instantiated so there's no possibility to use these members.

However, static members in non-static class can be used without having class instance - a bit different scenario, i.e. for utility methods or factory methods.

Answer (score -1):

Say you have a class Person that has a field name.  And let's suppose, for the sake of argument, that Java did allow static methods to directly access non-static member variables.  We might then specify a getName static method for our Person like so:

```
class Person {
  private final String name;

  public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public static String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Now let's try using this class in an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Person alice = new Person("Alice");
  Person bob = new Person("Bob");
  System.out.println("name: " + Person.getName());
}
```

So tell me, what on earth would we expect Person.getName() to print in this example?  Alice?  Bob?  Null?

There's no right answer.  It makes no sense, because a name is something that belongs to an individual (an instance), not the class as a whole.  So clearly we cannot have a static method access non-static members because we have no way of knowing which non-static members we should be accessing.