# public variables and scope in C#

Tags: c#, variables, scope

It is my understanding that a public variable declared at the class level of a program was available everywhere else in the program.

In the following code:

```
namespace Lab13
{
    class Program
    {
       int lower = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a lower bound number:");


            lower = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

---

I get a compile error with regards to my assignment of lower.

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: Put 'public' in front of variable declaration.  Class also need to be public.

Comment: The issue with your code is static/instance; nothing to do with public/private

Comment: What does the error say exactly? It might hint something about instance variables (it needs to be static)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an instance field, and instance members couldn't be accessed from static members.

Since I see that it's just a sample code, changing `int lower` to `static int lower` will be sufficient to access the whole field from `Main` method.

Comment: Please try to not answer questions that have been answered hundreds of times on this site. Just flag them as a duplicate.

Comment: @Dispersia Yeah, I've found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572554/unable-to-use-instance-variable-in-a-static-method. I've voted to re-open this Q&A to be able to mark it as duplicate...

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes, which no one could understand them as my answer addresses OP's problem.