# Why members in static class are not static by default

Tags: c#

My question is why members are not by default **static** in **static class**.

As we see, interface members are by default public and abstract.

Thanks,
Anil

Comment: Interface members are indeed public and abstract, that's by definition. You cannot create a private member in an interface.

Comment: [Why can't static classes have non-static methods and variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783828/why-cant-static-classes-have-non-static-methods-and-variables)

Answer (score 0):

We should ask c# language designer.

But I understand the ratio behind: it forces the programmer to say "this function is static", even if it would be implied by the fact the the class is static.

Maybe It's a matter of readability: when you read a method without body (and no abstract keyword), you know that this method can only be part of an interface.
When you read a method without "static" modifier, you would need to read also class declaration to understand that is part of a static class and therefore static itself

Comment: Well, in the duplicate a C# language designer actually answered :D

Comment: @codroipo I was not far from his explanation :D